# Set/Edit multi line column: user/date entry in SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, multiline-text-field

I got a multi line column('Comment') which is set up to add changes/new entries. When an entry is added, the date and user appears on the left side. I am able to add entry using `Set-PnPListItem`, but my name and current date appears.

I need to set different user and date within that 'Comment' column (not the author/editor of the whole item). 
Is it possible to accomplish that using pnp or any other way?

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "My list" -Identity $itemID -Values @{"Comment" = "Test Comment"}
```

Example:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [-SystemUpdate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) Here is example with Author.

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "My list" -Identity $ItemID -Values @{"Author" = "Name.User@domain.onmicrosoft.com"} -SystemUpdate
Set-PnPListItem -List "My list" -Identity $ItemID -Values @{"Editor" = "User.Name@domain.onmicrosoft.com"} -SystemUpdate
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I believe your example will change the Author for the whole item. But I need to change Author and Date withing the multi line column ('Comment') itself, for each comment that i am adding.

Comment: this comment existed with versioning? Or its custom multiline ? look to the link at MS documentation to -Values, this is probably user who made the changes, so you probably need somehow work "as different user" and add this comment